Failing JWT Authentication in spring with async requests
Hello everyone I wrote an api Backend in Spring and added jwt Authentication. The problem is that I wrote everything async and now the Authentication doesnt work with the async methodes. The token is right and works with non async methodes. It looks like there are two requests but there is only one. Those are the logs:
2024-12-01T14:06:14.483+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/videos/057aed00-6ac6-4353-aec7-be0faf5835c1/like
2024-12-01T14:06:14.490+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] c.d.d.JwtAuthenticationFilter            : Start of doFilterInternal: Request URL: http://localhost:8010/api/videos/057aed00-6ac6-4353-aec7-be0faf5835c1/like
2024-12-01T14:06:14.565+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] c.d.d.JwtAuthenticationFilter            : Extracted username from JWT: 1234
Hibernate: select u1_0.uuid,u1_0.banned,u1_0.beta_key,u1_0.daily_quest_id,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.followers,u1_0.password,u1_0.profile_picture,u1_0.username,u1_0.verification_code,u1_0.verification_expiration from users u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: select q1_0.uuid,q1_0.description,q1_0.dislikes,q1_0.likes,q1_0.title from quest q1_0 where q1_0.uuid=?
2024-12-01T14:06:14.701+01:00  INFO 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] c.d.d.JwtAuthenticationFilter            : Authentication successfully set for user: 1234
2024-12-01T14:06:14.704+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /api/videos/057aed00-6ac6-4353-aec7-be0faf5835c1/like
2024-12-01T14:06:14.784+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] c.d.d.JwtAuthenticationFilter            : End of doFilterInternal: Authentication: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=com.dayquest.dayquestbackend.user.User@99881f6, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]
Hibernate: select u1_0.uuid,u1_0.banned,u1_0.beta_key,dq1_0.uuid,dq1_0.description,dq1_0.dislikes,dq1_0.likes,dq1_0.title,u1_0.email,u1_0.enabled,u1_0.followers,u1_0.password,u1_0.profile_picture,u1_0.username,u1_0.verification_code,u1_0.verification_expiration from users u1_0 left join quest dq1_0 on dq1_0.uuid=u1_0.daily_quest_id where u1_0.uuid=?
Hibernate: select v1_0.uuid,v1_0.description,v1_0.down_votes,v1_0.file_path,v1_0.quest_uuid,v1_0.thumbnail,v1_0.title,v1_0.up_votes,v1_0.user_id from video v1_0 where v1_0.uuid=?
Hibernate: select lv1_0.user_id,lv1_0.video_id from liked_videos lv1_0 where lv1_0.user_id=?
2024-12-01T14:06:15.144+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/videos/057aed00-6ac6-4353-aec7-be0faf5835c1/like
2024-12-01T14:06:15.144+01:00 DEBUG 24364 --- [nio-8010-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext

and this is the code:
@PostMapping("/{uuid}/like")
  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Video>> likeVideo(
          @PathVariable UUID uuid,
          @RequestBody UuidDTO userUuid,
          Principal principal) {

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try {
        // Use the current authentication directly
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth == null || !auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }

        User currentUser = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(userUuid.getUuid()));
        Optional<Video> video = videoRepository.findById(uuid);

        // Verify the user matches the authenticated user
        if (user.isEmpty() || !user.get().getEmail().equals(currentUser.getEmail())) {
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }

        if (user.get().getLikedVideos().contains(uuid)) {
          return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE).build();
        }

        if (user.get().getDislikedVideos().contains(uuid)) {
          user.get().getDislikedVideos().remove(uuid);
          video.get().setDownVotes(video.get().getDownVotes() - 1);
          videoRepository.save(video.get());
        }

        user.get().getLikedVideos().add(uuid);
        userRepository.save(user.get());
        return videoService.likeVideo(uuid).join();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
      }
    }, delegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor);
  }

My async config:
package com.dayquest.dayquestbackend;

import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor;
import org.springframework.security.task.DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-task-");
        executor.initialize();

        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor delegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor) {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor);
    }
}


package com.dayquest.dayquestbackend;

import com.dayquest.dayquestbackend.user.User;
import com.dayquest.dayquestbackend.user.UserRepository;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    public SecurityConfiguration(JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/auth/**",
                                "/api/users/auth",
                                "/api/users/login",
                                "/api/users/register",
                                "/swagger-ui/**",
                                "/v3/**",
                                "/api/users/verify",
                                "/api/users/resendcode"
                        ).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                        exceptionHandling
                                .authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
                                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                                    response.getWriter().write("Authentication failed: " + authException.getMessage());
                                })
                                .accessDeniedHandler((request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
                                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
                                    response.getWriter().write("Access denied: " + accessDeniedException.getMessage());
                                })
                )
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return username -> {
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + username);
            }
            return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                    .withUsername(user.getEmail())
                    .password(user.getPassword())
                    .authorities(Collections.emptyList())
                    .build();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
    }
}



My filter:
package com.dayquest.dayquestbackend;

import com.dayquest.dayquestbackend.JwtService;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtService jwtService, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.debug("Start of doFilterInternal: Request URL: {}", request.getRequestURL());
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            logger.debug("No valid Authorization header found. Proceeding without authentication.");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        try {
            final String jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            final String username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);

            logger.debug("Extracted username from JWT: {}", username);

            // Proceed only if username is not null and no authentication is set
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails,
                            null,
                            userDetails.getAuthorities()
                    );
                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                    // Set SecurityContext
                    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                    securityContext.setAuthentication(authToken);
                    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

                    logger.info("Authentication successfully set for user: {}", username);
                } else {
                    logger.warn("Invalid JWT token for user: {}", username);
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
                    response.getWriter().write("Invalid token");
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Proceed with the filter chain
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred during JWT processing", e);
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.getWriter().write("Authentication failed: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            logger.debug("End of doFilterInternal: Authentication: {}", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
        }
    }
}


I tried with a delegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor in the AsyncConfig but this didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You are mixing two different concepts. The first concept is vanilla Java multithreading the second is Spring Async method execution.

By using a CompletableFuture you are creating a new Java Thread.
Spring can not help you there. If you want to pass the Security
Context you would have to do it manually. For example by reading the
jwt token in the original thread and passing it as a parameter in
the new created thread.

The Second approach would be using Spring "Async" annotation. There you would have to call a method normally and spring creates the "new Thread" under the hood.
@Async
public void doSomeAsyncCalls() throws {
Thread.sleep(1000); // Security Context can be passed by spring
System.out.println("Test0");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Test1");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Test2");
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Test3");
}
In this case Spring can help you by using the approach you already tried correctly  with the DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor. It is however not possible to return parameters when using Spring "Async".
I would also suggest that you name your async-task-executor explicitly. It ensures that your config is used and when someone reads the code he can understand not the defaul asyncTaskExecutor that is provided by spring is used.
@Bean(name = "myCustomAsyncTaskExecutor")
public Executor asyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-task-");
    executor.initialize();

    return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
}

@Async(name = "myCustomAsyncTaskExecutor")
public void doSomeAsyncCalls() throws {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // Security Context can be passed by spring 
    System.out.println("Test0");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Test1");
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
    System.out.println("Test2");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("Test3");
} 



